# How to check if do_shortcode will be execute directly in a template php file

Tags: custom-taxonomy, shortcode

I have a template for a specific taxonomy :

**taxonomy-mytaxonomy.php**

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

get_header( );
?>

<!-- Content -->
<div id="content" class="content" role="main">

    <?php
    the_archive_description( '<div class="taxonomy-description">', '</div>' );

    if ( have_posts() ) {
        $queried_object = get_queried_object();
        $term_slug = $queried_object->slug;
        $shortcode = sprintf( '[my-shortcode attr1="value1" /]',
            $term_slug
        );
        echo do_shortcode($shortcode);
    } else {
        get_template_part( 'no-results', 'search' );
    }
    ?>

</div><!-- #content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

In an other php file I need to check if do_shortcode will be run with `my-shortcode` tag to enqueue styles and scripts.

```
public function check_page(){      
    global $post;
    if( !empty( $post->post_content ) && has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'my-shortcode' ) ){
        add_action( "wp_enqueue_scripts", array( $this, "set_scripts" ) );
    }
}
```

In my case, I cannot use `has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'my-shortcode' )` because it´s not in a `post_content` but directly inside the template php file.

Soemone has got an idea ?

Comment: If you know that your taxonomy template uses a shortcode, then just check `is_tax( ‘mytaxonomy’ )`. The specific use of that function doesn’t particularly matter.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.
First of all, the best way seems to not use `do_shortcode` direclty in the php.
You can know more [here](https://rocketgeek.com/basics/why-you-should-not-use-do_shortcode/).

So...

**taxonomy-mytaxonomy.php**

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

get_header( );
?>

<!-- Content -->
<div id="content" class="content" role="main">

    <?php
    the_archive_description( '<div class="taxonomy-description">', '</div>' );

    if ( have_posts() ) {
        $queried_object = get_queried_object();
        $term_slug = $queried_object->slug;
        $atts = [
            'attr1' => "value1"
        ];
        echo ListCPTShortcode::getCallBack( $atts, null, "my-shortcode" );
    } else {
        get_template_part( 'no-results', 'search' );
    }
    ?>

</div><!-- #content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

To enqueue scripts and styles, I did this

**my-theme/functions.php**

```
function my_shortcode_category_load( $content ){
    $current_post = get_queried_object();
    if( !empty( $current_post ) && isset( $current_post->taxonomy ) &&  $current_post->taxonomy === "mytaxonomy" ){
          wp_enqueue_style(...);
          wp_enqueue_script(...);
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( "the_content", "my_shortcode_category_load" );
```

Comment: That complicated `if` statement is entirely unnecessary. Just use `is_tax( 'mytaxonomy' )`. Also, it doesn't make any sense to use the `the_content` filter for that. Use the proper `wp_enqueue_scripts()` hook.

Comment: Why are you using a shortcode anyway? that's not the proper way to list posts in a template.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, `is_tax()` will return true on page like this `www.my-site/mytaxonomy/my-post-name` as well ?

Comment: @JacobPeattie, I have to use a shortcode because this file is in the child theme and the content to display is in a plugin I made.